# Design Pattern for object conversion

Tags: design-patterns

I am looking for advice on the best pattern to use for the following scenario.

Involves converting from a domain level object to a UI DTO

For the object in question, `BeanUtils` or `PropertyUtils` will perform most of the conversion.

My domain level object contains a "type" attribute. Based on this type, we need to set a DTO "label" property to a friendly name.

- So for type AAA, we need to create a label as follows: `property1 + "-" + property2`
- For type BBB, we need to create a label as follows: `property2 + "/" + property1`
- For type CCC, we need to create a label based on a database query

(The above logic is oversimplified)

Without researching all possible design patterns, I have the following pattern in mind:

1. Create a number of LabelCreationStrategies, one for each type
2. In my     object conversion helper, inject a map that maps "type" to strategy
3. So when the object conversion takes place, it will find the
   appropriate strategy, and create the most appropriate label.

What other patterns would work here?

Thanks

Comment: You could also make Type a polymorphic object where each Type (AAA, BBB) knows how to generate it's strategy.

Comment: @jeff: You could post this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Strategy pattern

```
 public abstract class AbstractClass{   //or interface 
       public abstract void print();
    }


    public class AAA extends AbstractClass{

        @Override
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("AAA");
        }
    }

    public class BBB extends AbstractClass{

        @Override
        public void print(){
            System.out.println("BBB");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change your Type to an actual object that knows how to generate the appropriate strategy.

For example:

```
 public interface Type {
   NamingStrategy getNamingStrategy();
 }

 public class AAA implements Type {
   public NamingStrategy getNamingStrategy() {
     return new DatabaseQueryStrategy();
   }

   public String toString() {
     return "AAA";
   }
 }
```